# Advice on Android Plugin App Design

Tags: android, plugins, integrate

I have an existing application which displays Song Lyrics (Lyric Pad) and has a fast menu system.

I am looking at creating an additional application that will play backing tracks (mp3s) for musicians.  Idealy I would like the Backing Track application to be a plugin for my song lyric application and would:

- Not need to be run as an application (would load with Lyric Pad)
- Would use the Lyric Pad menu system (ie. when a song is open the corresponding backing track is played)
- Would add additioanl preferences to the Lyric Pad preferences system

As I have never tried a plugin style app I was hoping someone could provide some advice on the best way to design this plugin and possibly point me to some examples / tutorials.